# Web Page is Mysteriously Long in Chrome

Tags: html, css, dom, google-chrome, webkit

Check out the bottom of this page in Chrome (10.0.648.134): http://seatgeek.com/jobs/

The page mysteriously extends well beyond the footer.  I'm perplexed by this because:

- Looking a the web inspector, the web inspector is saying that the html ends at the end of the footer, so it's hard to know how to debug this.
- This only happens in Chrome (not even Safari)
- It doesn't happen on any other pages on my site except for the jobs pages

This isn't JS-related; I've turned off JS and it still happens.

Comment: can you post a screendump? I don't see any of your reported behaviour on my chrome ;)

Comment: Sure thing, here you go: http://cl.ly/5Jn9.  Interesting that you don't see it.  What version of Chrome are you on?

Comment: Jack, I wonder if this is something with Chrome 10.x?  In 9.0.597.107 the footer's end is flush with the bottom of the page. (fyi: this is how it appears in Chrome 9: http://cl.ly/2n0O303l0Z1Z460e0W3V)  Very odd!

Comment: Thanks Rob.  Yeah, I think it must be Chrome version-specific.  Still odd b/c it's only showing up on these job pages for us, and (as far as I know) there's nothing special about the markup here.

Comment: Very strange, in Chrome 10 the computed height of the `html` element is 1869px, just like in firefox, and that is just until the bottom of the footer it seems.

Comment: on 8.0.552.215 it looks like it seems to work.

Comment: I downloaded and installed fresh download of chrome 2 hours ago on a new pc and it shows this bug. Ver.: 10.0.648.134

Comment: Still broken in Chrome 11.0.696.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a reported chrome bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75815

I would wait for fix.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to validate your mark-up first. [There are a few errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://seatgeek.com/jobs/&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

I've seen strange behaviour before in Chrome with invalid mark-up. In fact it was a difference between Chrome 8 and 10 that caused problems for me in the past with invalid mark-up, so that might explain it.